# How do I use two-legged oauth with the python gdata library?

Tags: google-oauth, gdata-api, google-api-python-client, google-apps-marketplace, gdata-python-client

I am trying to access a list of users through an app. I cannot get two-legged auth to work. I want to be able to access google's APIs without requiring user consent after install. The gdata lib was deprecated earlier this year, but a business requirement requires accessing the APIs without additional user consent after the domain admin has installed the app.

Here is what I have done so far:

- I have created an application on the Marketplace. The app manifest declares this scope:

  `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/`
- I have installed my app in a test domain and granted permissions for the above scope.
- I have looked at the samples here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/oauth/

  - Deprecated `Service` approach: 2_legged_oauth.py
  - Updated `Client` approach: TwoLeggedOAuthExample.py

I am using Python 2.7.5 and gdata 2.0.18. Here is my code, which was adapted from the above mentioned examples:

```
import gdata.gauth
import gdata.apps.client

CONSUMER_KEY = "[snip].apps.googleusercontent.com"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "[snip]"
requestor_id = 'myuser@mydomain.com'

client = gdata.apps.client.AppsClient(domain='mydomain.com', source='myapp-v1')
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(
    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, requestor_id)
client.ssl = True

# Failure occurs here.
feed = client.RetrieveAllUsers()
```

The response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unknown authorization header</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unknown authorization header</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here are the details for the headers being sent:

```
GET /a/feeds/mydomain.com/user/2.0?xoauth_requestor_id=myuser%40mydomain.com HTTP/1.1
Host: apps-apis.google.com
Accept-Encoding: identity
GData-Version: 2.0
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="035378574830673", oauth_timestamp="1383593346", oauth_consumer_key="[snip].apps.googleusercontent.com", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="[snip]"
User-Agent: test-test-v1 gdata-py/2.0.18
```

Here is debugging information on the response (as taken from putting atom.http_core.ProxiedHttpClient into debug mode):

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unknown authorization header\r\n'
header: WWW-Authenticate: GoogleLogin realm="http://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", service="apps"
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:33:35 GMT
header: Expires: Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:33:35 GMT
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Server: GSE
header: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

How do I use use two-legged oauth to access users on a domain? I am open to using the newer Google API clients (`oauth2client` and `apiclient`), but only if I can use two-legged authentication since I have a business requirement to not have the third leg.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to [read](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) [the](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#SignedJwtAssertionCredentials) regarding OAuth2 Service Accounts.

2-legged-OAuth is deprecated, gdata APIs are largely deprecated and apiclient services are much cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: I was under the impression that I could not use a service account due to the following:
1. http://goo.gl/NDZLj2 - Only certain APIs are supported (>1 year old)
2. your link http://goo.gl/fj9KdX says "act on behalf of an application without accessing user information". I believe I need to access user info.
3. This SO q/a also says that I cannot access user info with a service account: http://goo.gl/utY5us

Comment: If I can use service accounts to access what I want (Admin SDK, Directory API) then I'd much rather use that, I was just under the impression that it was not supported since I will be accessing user data. Is that not accurate?

Comment: My only aversion to using the newer libs and APIs is that I have a business requirement that prevents the third-leg of the OAuth2 flow (additional user consent).

Comment: Please read again the doc (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and search for Additional Claims ("prn"). It IS possible to impersonate a user with Service Accounts no matter what a 3,742 reputation score user says. We do. You should be able too.

Comment: The example given in the python api library does not use a 'prn': https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py

Comment: Just add a prn=username@thedomain in the SignedJwtAssertionCredentials constructor call and the calls made with this credentials will be made on behalf of that user.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've been having the exact problem when trying to use oauth2 with gdata. (i am actually migrating code from oauth1 to oauth2, so i have two limitations: using service accounts and using gdata library). How did you solve the problem ?

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it with this pattern in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925125/accesstokenrefresherror-google-spreadsheet-api-with-oauth-2-0-service-account-o